# Using selenium to handle Chrome Web Store confirmation window in Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to write a script that installs the OneLogin Extension because OneLogin is required to visit the website.

I can get selenium to input the user name and password to complete the login itself, but I still need the extension to access the site otherwise the credentials will not be loaded. I tried to convert my current installed plugin to .crx file and let the webdriver to import upon startup but it does not work. The browser still asks me if I want to install the OneLogin extension every time. This is how I load the extension if you are interested.

```
# load extension
# extension='.../3.4.46_0.crx'
# options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_extension(extension)
```

So I am going the other option which is install the plugin every time I create a webdriver instance. This approach I have faced one problem. For example when you try to install an extension (any extension is fine), a pop up window asking "Add X?" "It can ......" and then you are given the option of "cancel" and "Add extension".
[image: Window example]

I am having trouble on how to click "Add extension" button. I cannot inspect element, it does nothing. The old element will not work because it is in a different location. I have tried the capture "alert" approach but it failed. I suspect this works if it is part of the html, but the new pop up window information is not coded in the download page, probably behind a javascript.

I tried to use the Robot framework, but it seems to work for the Java version only. Also it seems that selenium does not allow you just to click at coordinate (x,y). So what should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a simple mistake of initiate the webdriver before loading options. Now the chrome preloads with the plugin upon launching.

```
# load extension
extension='/Users/wang.shuochen/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/ioalpmibngobedobkmbhgmadaphocjdn/3.4.46_0.crx'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_extension(extension)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/wang.shuochen/Downloads/chromedriver", options=options)
```